# How do I deploy my Vue js SPA into my Django server?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm currently following this guide on integrating my Vue.js frontend with my Django backend: https://medium.com/@williamgnlee/simple-integrated-django-vue-js-web-application-configured-for-heroku-deployment-c4bd2b37aa70

For now, I just want to be able to render the default Vue.js boilerplate [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAPyN.png) page into my Django server at http://localhost:8000/

I used `django-admin startproject django-vue-template` to initialize Django and within the newly created django-vue-template folder, I ran `vue create .` to initialize Vue CLI. I then ran `npm run build`, so my project folder tree looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pknKe.png) now.

I also added these changes to my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist/static'),
]
```

as well as these changes to my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

According to the guide, I should already be seeing the Vue.js [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAPyN.png) page on http://localhost:8000/ when I run `python manage.py runserver` but nothing renders except a white screen and when I check the console, I'm bombarded with error 404s as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e310.png).

Django seems to be able to locate my index.html, but it can't find and import the css and js files it needs to make its SPA functionality work.

Comment: Can you add your index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You must configure it manually**
Make sure at the top of index.html must have :

```
{% load static %}
```

then all links looks like:

```
<script src="{% static "app.d34dcca9.js" %}"></script>
```

same as css files or images.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem with the following settings `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  assetsDir: 'static',
```